# How to enable spell check functionality of Apache Solr using contrib modules?

Tags: search

Apache Solr is designed to provide inline spell checking which basically makes suggestions if it thinks you have misspelt a word. I am trying to work out what is the most simplest way of implementing this.  I have not been able to find any specific contributed modules which provide this functionality.

Is it possible to set this up with contrib modules or must one set it up directly in Solr configuration?

Comment: check this link http://knackforge.com/blog/selvam/drupal-7-and-solr-autocompleting-full-node-title

Answer (score 0):

Use search api spellcheck module for this
https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_spellcheck